# Arduino SocketIoClient - no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, arduino, bind

Im trying to use SocketIoClient from [Here](https://github.com/timum-viw/socket.io-client/). When im doing that in main.cpp file everything works fine. But when I trying to use webSocket inside my own class im getting errors.

```
//.h 
#include <SocketIoClient.h>
class SocketClient
{
   public:
     SocketClient();
     void setup();
 private:
     SocketIoClient webSocket;
     void handleData(const char * payload, size_t length);
};

//.cpp file:
#include "SocketClient.h"

SocketClient::SocketClient(){

}
void SocketClient::setup(){
  webSocket.on("data", std::bind(&SocketClient::handleData, this));
}
void SocketClient::handleData(const char * payload, size_t length) {
    Serial.print("handleData (" + String(length) + "):");
    Serial.println(payload);
}
```

And im getting this stacktrace:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'SocketIoClient::on(const char [10], std::_Bind_helper<false, void (SocketClient::*)(const char*, unsigned int), SocketClient* const>::type)'
webSocket.on("stageData", std::bind(&SocketClient::handleData, this));
^
lib\socket.io-client-master/SocketIoClient.h:41:7: note: void SocketIoClient::on(const char*, std::function<void(const char*, unsigned int)>)
void on(const char* event, std::function<void (const char * payload, size_t length)>);
^
lib\socket.io-client-master/SocketIoClient.h:41:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'std::_Bind_helper<false, void (SocketClient::*)(const char*, unsigned int), SocketClient* const>::type {aka std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (SocketClient::*)(const char*, unsigned int)>(SocketClient*)>}' to 'std::function<void(const char*, unsigned int)>'
```

How can this work in my class?

Here is webSocket.on function:

```
void on(const char* event, std::function<void (const char * payload, size_t length)>);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `std::placeholders::X` to tell that 
your member function takes 2 parameters, these parameters 
should be unbound because the function object created by 
`std::bind` will be triggered by `webSocket` object and this object 
will provide arguments to your callback while calling it.

```
callback = bind(,_1,_2); // create callback
```

Somewhere in webSocket`s method:

```
callback ("params",20);
```

So write

```
webSocket.on("data", std::bind(&SocketClient::handleData, this, 
 std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2));
```